# WPF C# : Scroll TreeView Children instead of scrolling the entire container

Tags: wpf, treeview, scrollbar, containers, children

I'm having a problem with a TreeView in WPF C#.
I have a TreeView with two TreeViewItems defined in XAML.
On the second TreeViewItem, I have a list of items defined by a binding.
When the list is too long, a vertical scrollbar appears and allows the entire TreeView to scroll.
But the two TreeViewItems must stay at the same place, so I'd like the content of the second to scroll instead, rather than the entire TreeView.
[Left : what I get, and the two first items are scrolled out; Right what I'd like, with the two first items staying at the same spot. (The scrollbar is the red zone).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGzIV.png)

I look forward to hearing from you guys, and thanks in advance,

Raekh.

EDIT :
Found a solution : I removed the two treeviewitems and used a treeview with a item source obtained by binding, so the treeview starts after the treeviewitems and is scrolled properly.